# Right Click menu doesn't show up on Firefox (smartgwt)

Tags: smartgwt

If have a Canvas with elements on it where a right-click should open a menu for this element. This works fine in IE. In Mozilla it only works as long a no scrollbar is visible. If I smallen the window the menu won't show up even though the event is called. I tried the menu.show(), menu.showContextMenu() and menu.showNextTo() method but neither worked. The simple code snippet looks like this. Is there a reason why this is happening?

```
final Menu appMenu = new Menu();
MenuItem smallItem = new MenuItem("Test");
appMenu.addItem(smallItem);

// Context Menu open
this.addRightMouseDownHandler(new RightMouseDownHandler() {

  @Override
  public void onRightMouseDown(RightMouseDownEvent event) {
      appMenu.show();
      // appMenu.showNextTo(Canvas.this);
      System.out.println("rmb");
      event.cancel();
 }
});
```

Comment: this code is not sufficient. can u post a stand alone code so that we can also reproduce it? By the way, have you used **canvas.setContextMenu(appMenu)**?

Comment: No I didn't try this before, I wasn't aware of such a function. I tried it and it works perfectly fine in both browsers. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `canvas.setContextMenu(appMenu)`.